# Rails 3.1 set up to run app in parallel with HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ssl, https, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do you guys set up your Rails 3.1 app to run HTTP and HTTPS in parallel on production?

Also how do you share the session between HTTP and HTTPS?

Thanks

Comment: If the app can run in HTTP or HTTPS mode, why even use HTTPS? What's your goal?

Comment: I specifically want to use HTTPS for logging in and signing up. The main page will be redirected to HTTP as it  contains insecure content and doesn't really need any security on it. Other pages can be either HTTPS or HTTP depending on the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [bartt/ssl_requirement](https://github.com/bartt/ssl_requirement) which allows you to secure certain actions, like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ::SslRequirement
end

class AccountController < ApplicationController
  ssl_required :signup, :payment
  ...
end
```

For paths, you simply set `:secure => true`:

```
<% form_tag session_path(:secure => true), :class => 'home_login' do -%>
```

To disable in development, add this in the configure block of `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
  config.after_initialize do
    SslRequirement.disable_ssl_check = true
  end
```

And if you use a secure subdomain like I do on Heroku, you can add this to config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.after_initialize do
  SslRequirement.ssl_host = 'secure.example.com'
end
```

as well as `:domain => :all` to `config/initializers/session_store.rb` so the session is shared across all domains. e.g.:

```
MyAppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myappname_session', :domain => :all
```